Failure to mock global.fetch() function
// evaluator.ts
export class Evaluator {
  private functionRegistry: FunctionRegistry;

  constructor(functionRegistry: FunctionRegistry) {
    this.functionRegistry = functionRegistry;
  }

  async evaluate(expression: Expression): Promise<AcceptedTypes> {
    if (!expression || !expression.type) {
      throw new Error("Invalid expression");
    }
    switch (expression.type) {
      case "literal":
        return (expression as LiteralExpression).value;
      case "function":
        return await this.evaluateFunction(expression as FunctionExpression);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unknown expression type ${expression.type}`);
    }
  }

  async evaluateFunction(expression: FunctionExpression) {
    if (!this.functionRegistry.functionMap.hasOwnProperty(expression.name)) {
      throw new Error(`Unknown function name ${expression.name}`);
    }
    const func = this.functionRegistry.functionMap[expression.name];
    const evaluatedParams = await Promise.all(
      expression.parameters.map((param) => this.evaluate(param))
    );
    return await func(evaluatedParams);
  }
}

// evaluator.test.ts file
let evaluator: Evaluator;
let functionRegistry: jest.Mocked<FunctionRegistry>;

const fetchGetExpression = {
  type: "function",
  name: "contains",
  parameters: [
    {
      type: "function",
      name: "fetchGet",
      parameters: [
        {
          type: "literal",
          value: "https://google.com",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      type: "literal",
      value: "Bing",
    },
  ],
};

describe("Evaluator", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    functionRegistry = {
      functionMap: {},
      registerFunction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function (name, func) {
        functionRegistry.functionMap[name] = func;
      }),
    };

    functionRegistry.registerFunction("contains", jest.fn());
    functionRegistry.registerFunction("add", jest.fn());
    functionRegistry.registerFunction("equals", jest.fn());
    functionRegistry.registerFunction("not", jest.fn());
    functionRegistry.registerFunction("fetchGet", jest.fn());
    global.fetch = jest.fn();

    evaluator = new Evaluator(functionRegistry);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

it("should return true when fetchGet retrieves a response containing the expected text", async () => {
    functionRegistry.functionMap["contains"] = jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValueOnce(true);
    functionRegistry.functionMap["fetchGet"] = jest
      .fn()
      .mockResolvedValue("This contains Bing in a sentence");

    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      ok: true,
      text: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue("This contains Bing in a sentence"),
    });

    const result = await evaluator.evaluate(fetchGetExpression);

    expect(result).toBe(true);
    expect(functionRegistry.functionMap["fetchGet"]).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      "https://google.com",
    ]);
    expect(functionRegistry.functionMap["contains"]).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      "This contains Bing in a sentence",
      "Bing",
    ]);
    expect(functionRegistry.functionMap["fetchGet"]).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://google.com");
  });
});

// functions.ts file
export async function fetchGet(url: string): Promise<string> {
  console.log("here I am");
  const response = await global.fetch(url);
  console.log("aaaa", response);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to retrieve url ${url}`);
  }
  return await response.text();
}

I'm having difficulties with mocking global.fetch() function.
Expected: "https://google.com"

    Number of calls: 0

      614 |     ]);
      615 |     expect(functionRegistry.functionMap["fetchGet"]).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    > 616 |     expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://google.com");

I was able to work this test when I wasn't using FunctionRegistry class. When I defined that class and passed the instance to the evaluator I had to change the test cases. Now I'm not able to fix that test.

Please provide the code of Evaluator, show us how does it use the functionRegistry object

Hello @LinDu I've provided the Evaluator class, thanks.
